# How to place a dictionary variable in a separate swift file?

Tags: swift, class, variables

The project needs a big Dictionary, so I place it in anohher swift file that makes the codes look clean. But I got a "Expected declaration" error.

```
class AA{

    var a:Dictionary<String,Array<String>> = [:]
    a["a"] = ["aa", "aaa"] // error: Expected declaration
    ...
    ...

}
```

and I want to get it like this:

```
let aa = AA.a
```

By now, I have to add it in a func to get it.

```
class AA{

    func getVar()->Dictionary<String,Array<String>>{

        var a:Dictionary<String,Array<String>> = [:]
        a["a"] = ["aa", "aaa"]
        a["b"] = ["bb", "bbb"]

        return a
    }

}
```

Any simple way to solve this?

@dasblinkenlight your suggestion is get variable from another viewController, it's a little difference from mine.

Comment: `Expected declaration` means the code **must** run within a function / method. You cannot run code on the top level of the class. And `AA.a` won't work anyway because it's not a type property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift accessing variable from another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002847/swift-accessing-variable-from-another-file)

Comment: Unrelated, by why don't you clean this up with a Dictionary literal? http://pastebin.com/cVcThQ3p

Comment: @Alexander This is not unrelated at all - that's exactly his problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh I just saw the first code snippet. Kinda glanced over the question :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you have a dictionary in another file, but that you have assignments outside of a method.

Replacing assignments with a declaration will fix this problem:

```
class AA {
    static let a = [
        "a" : ["aa", "aaa"]
    ,   "b" : ["bb", "bbb", "bbbb"]
    ,   "c" : ["cc"]
    ]
}
```

Now you can use `AA.a` in other classes.

Comment: SQL commas in Swift? Et tu, Brute?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding , You can't access local variables from another class, You can access it in only of that class method only.

Accessing var from another class,

```
var someVariable: Type = xValue
```

Now create object of that class where you have declared variable & access it like,

```
var getThatValue = yourViewControllerObject.someVariable
```

Access var with in the same class,

```
 self.yourVar
```

Or,

```
static let yourProperty = 0


ClassName.yourProperty  //  & for swift 3 it would be type(of: self).yourProperty
```

This interesting topic is discussed nicely in the following links,

[Access variable in different class - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333142/access-variable-in-different-class-swift)

[Access static variables within class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952670/access-static-variables-within-class-in-swift)

**In your case i think you have to declare var as a static out of method scope**